Python typing and Redis asyncio: telling the type checker to expect an Awaitable
Minimal example:
import redis.asyncio as redis

client = redis.Redis()
client.hset(key, mapping=...)

Pylance complains about it like so:
"int" is not awaitable
  "int" is incompatible with protocol "Awaitable[_T_co@Awaitable]"
    "__await__" is not presentPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues

hset is declared as (Awaitable[int] | int).
The simplest solution seems to be to cast(Awaitable, client.hset(...)). Is there any other, dry-er way to tell the type-checker that I am expecting all Redis commands to return an Awaitable so I don't have to cast() to Awaitable every time I touch Redis?

Duplicate: How do I get Pylance to ignore the possibility of None?. Slightly different problem but same answer.
